# "It may have been her brother" Why do we use IT instead of HE?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns

I read the following in *English Grammar in Use* book (app):

> Who was the man we saw with Anna yesterday?
>
> I don't know. **It** may have been her brother.

Why do they use "it" instead of "he"?

Generally, when do we use "it" instead of "he" or "she"?

**Update:**

So, Does *It* use here as an empty *(dummy) subject*, or as pronoun of *unidentified* person?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a **dummy it** or **anticipatory it**.  We often use **it** to refer to facts or the existence or nature of something.  Every English sentence must have a subject, but sometimes when we're talking about the nature or existence of something, we use *it* as a placeholder subject.  For example,

> It is raining.
>   It was good to see you yesterday.
>   It was Janet at the door.

In that last example, saying "**She** was Janet at the door" is wrong, because we're really talking about a fact or a phenomenon, not the nature of a particular female person; we use **it** to *anticipate* the fact that is revealed later in the sentence.

References:

- [Uses of *It*](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/minor/dummy.htm)
- [dummy "it" (grammar)](http://grammar.about.com/od/d/g/Dummy-It.htm)
- [Dummy subjects](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/about-words-clauses-and-sentences/dummy-subjects)

Answer (score 2):

This "it" is not only an empty subject used to introduce the real subject -- it refers to a person mentioned in the context that was, up to that moment, unidentified.

On page 349 of "A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language" by Quirk *et al* we find an interesting example with its explanation:

"The bell rang, and I went to the door. **It** was Dr Long. (4)"

That "it" refers to **the person who rang the bell**.

Quirk says: "To make full sense of sentences like (4), we have to supply, for example: It was Dr Long (who had rung the bell)."

Similarly, in your example:

A: Who was the man we saw with Anna yesterday?
B: I don't know. **It** may have been her brother.

"It" refers to the unknown, unidentified man that was seen with Anna yesterday. Once the person **has been identified**, a personal pronoun will be used to refer to him. Notice the change of pronoun if the conversation goes on:

A: Who was the man we saw with Anna yesterday?
B: I don't know. **It** may have been her brother.
A: Well, whoever **it** was, **he** looked like a nice guy.

Comment: I would be more inclined to say *Whoever he was, he looked like a nice guy*.

Comment: @verbose You may be right. That would confirm my point that the second time the person is mentioned the personal "he" or "she" will apply.